# Ternary operator as operand of ternary operator in C macro

Tags: c, macros, ternary-operator

I'm trying to implement Sieve of Erathostenes to get prime bits of an `unsigned long` array, so I wrote a macro to check the value of certain bit.. (function would be easier but it's school asignment so it has to be macro) I needed to test whether the index is in range of bits, so there is function call `FatalError`, which is void function with `exit(1)` call, so the comma operator makes the whole macro possible to be inside of condition

```
#define GetBit(array_name, index) \
  (((index) < (array_name)[0]) && ((index) >= 0)) ? \
  (((array_name)[((index) / BYTE) + 1] & ( (unsigned long)1 << \
    ((index) % BYTE))) ? 1 : 0) : \
  (FatalError("Index %ld out of range 0..%ld\n", (long)(index), \
    (long)(array_name)[0]), 0)
```

More readable form:

```
#define GetBit(array_name, index) \
  (range check) ? \
  ((bit shift, and) ? 1 : 0) : \
  (function call, 0)
```

On `array_name[0]`, there is the size of the array in bits.

So my problem is, that not even the first index can get through range check, the Sieve starts with index 2 and the program immediately ends with

```
~ $ gcc primes.c fatalerror.c -pedantic -Wall -g -std=c99 -lm; ./a.out
FATAL ERROR: Index 2 out of range 0..1000
~ $
```

Comment: `FatalError` is a `void()`? So you're calling something like `condition ? 1 : void();` I'm surprised that that even compiles.

Comment: that's what the comma operator is for, condition gets 0 (but it doesn't because of `exit` in `FatalError`)

Comment: I need to see the complete source too. I put this in a C program, but what I made just works.

Comment: [Your code works at ideone](http://ideone.com/uFiHb). Provide more code ...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HFBpw02F only the fatalerror is missing in there

Comment: and to explain the last lines of Erathostenes, I should write last 10 prime numbers in ascending order

Comment: If you run `gcc -E`, you will get the output of the preprocessor.  Check that it matches your expectation.

Comment: also when you develop macros `clang` as a compiler is really helpful, if you are on a platform that supports this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems, that the problem was in Erathostenes function in

```
if( ! GetBit(pole, m) )
```

with the `!` macro of course expanded as,

```
!(range check) ? op1 : op2
```

so the condition was negated

I removed the exclamation mark and switched the return operands of `op1`

```
((shift, and) ? 0 : 1)
```

on first look the values seem a little illogical, but work just fine

thanks to everyone for your time

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is a bug, so ignore the 'correct' form of answer, and make it easy for yourself to find the bug. It'll likely be quicker to find the problem if you go an easier route. As long as you try to stick with a single macro, it is likely to be harder to debug.

Concretely, I'd turn the macro into a function, to make it easier to debug, then break the expression down into component parts, and add a load of print statements to get a better understanding of what is happening:

```
printf("(((index) < (array_name)[0]) && ((index) >= 0)) = %d\n", 
        (((index) < (array_name)[0]) && ((index) >= 0)));
printf("(array_name)[((index) / BYTE) + 1] = %d\n", 
        (array_name)[((index) / BYTE) + 1]);
printf("( (unsigned long)1 << ((index) % BYTE)) = %d\n", 
        ( (unsigned long)1 << ((index) % BYTE)));
printf("BYTE=%d\n", BYTE);

// etc.
```

and redefine getbit to use

```
printf("Index %ld out of range 0..%ld\n", (long)(index), (long)(array_name)[0]);
```